# "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" - Why?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, type-inference

The code below fails to compile due to the red underlined `check`

[image]

screenshot added for the lambda parameter types, code:

```
handledExceptions.forEach { exceptionClass ->
    exceptionClassToHandler.compute(exceptionClass.java) { clazz, existingHandler ->
        check(null == existingHandler) { "There's already a handler registered for ${clazz.name}" }
        { e: Throwable -> handlerMethod.invoke(bean, exceptionClass.java.cast(e)) }
    }
}
```

For which it claims

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
[ERROR] public inline fun check(value: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin
[ERROR] public inline fun check(value: Boolean, lazyMessage: () -> Any): Unit defined in kotlin
```

Code compiles fine if I comment out the `check`.

(or replace it with

```
if(existingHandler != null){
    throw IllegalStateException("There's already a handler registered for ${clazz.name}")
}
```

)

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Why doesn't the check compile and how do I get it to?

Comment: Looks like you are passing two lambdas to the check function.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I'm not? The first one is supposed to be passed to the `check`, the other is meant to be the return of the `compute`?

Or are you telling me THAT's why Kotlin is complaining?

Comment: That's an issue in Kotlin compiler from early days. If you write a lambda even in next line, its still considered as an arg to the function. You can do two things: 1. Put a semicolon at the end of check function call line, 2. Use explicit return statement `return@compute {...}` you can modify labels by `compute(..) myLabel@ {..` to return with different label as `return@myLabel {...}`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That seems to have solved it. Thank you. Want to make an answer out of it, so I can accept it? ;)